# How to create an animation like the link below using canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am curious about how to create a canvas effect like the link below
http://rmp-api-server.herokuapp.com/demo/index.html
(There is an animation that follows the cursor.)

Comment: There is no real question here. How would you do this? You would write code. Have you tried to write any code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used that on my portfolio page about a year and a half back I guess.
The link is: https://codeaffair.com/portfolio/
You can check the source, nothing is minified.
Basically, the idea is to create many translucent circles on the page at random positions.

At every iteration of a draw method, move those circles some distance with respect to their original position(not the updated position). Draw lines on every circle to its 2-3 nearest neighbours. Done!

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I want and thanks for the explanation about the mechanics for this animation.